# Orgmode: Extra vertical space between level 1 and previous line

Tags: org-mode, themes

new to emacs, so if I'm mistaken with vocabulary, please excuse me.

I'm using orgmode, and I wish to modify the way it displays, specifically I wish to have some extra vertical distance before a level 1 task and the line before.

I found the `M-x customize-groups RET orgmode-faces RET` menu, and there are some options to customize org level 1 face, however not what I'm looking for.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I think I'm just not fluent in emacs speech to formulate the question correctly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be a better way, but the following can help.  From org [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Headlines.html#Headlines), if you insert more than one blank line before the heading, one blank line will be displayed:

> An empty line after the end of a subtree is considered part of it and
>   will be hidden when the subtree is folded.  However, if you leave at
>   least two empty lines, one empty line will remain visible after folding
>   the subtree, in order to structure the collapsed view.  See the variable
>   ‘org-cycle-separator-lines’ to modify this behavior.

As it says, this can be tweaked (`C-h v org-cycle-separator-lines`) for the variable doc string:

> Number of empty lines needed to keep an empty line between collapsed trees.
>   If you leave an empty line between the end of a subtree and the following
>   headline, this empty line is hidden when the subtree is folded.
>   Org-mode will leave (exactly) one empty line visible if the number of
>   empty lines is equal or larger to the number given in this variable.
>   So the default 2 means at least 2 empty lines after the end of a subtree
>   are needed to produce free space between a collapsed subtree and the
>   following headline.
>
> **If the number is negative, and the number of empty lines is at least -N,
>   all empty lines are shown**.

So if you set the variable to -2, and insert two blank lines, they will be displayed.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to tell emacs to always display an empty line between successive visible headings even if there is no empty line present?  Unfortunately org-cycle-separator-lines cannot be set to zero to achieve this effect :/

Comment: I don't know of any direct way, but I'm confident you could use a display property to achieve this (that is, visually adding an emply line before each heading). If you post this as a question I could provide an answer.