# Orgmode: Show some extra vertical space between level 1 and previous line

Tags: org-mode, faces, terminal-emacs

I want emacs to show put some vertical margin between my level 1 headers, so that they are more readable. Currently, they are really hard to read:
[image]

Compare with (I have manually added newlines between entries):
[image]

Note that I do NOT want to change my files, just how they are displayed. Bonus points for making the setting local to a file using some directive or something.

Kind of related (this question is fine with just inserting newlines manually):

- [Orgmode: Extra vertical space between level 1 and previous line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28040/orgmode-extra-vertical-space-between-level-1-and-previous-line)

Comment: I don't know the best way to do it but here's what I do: `(set-face-attribute 'org-level-1 nil :box 
\` (:line-width 8 :color ,(face-background 'default)))` . This unfortunately creates extra space on the left and right also.

Comment: @amitp This doesn't change anything for me, weirdly.

Comment: @amitp Perhaps that doesn't work in the terminal mode?

Comment: Some face properties might work in terminal emacs but most of them indeed will not.